# How is memory allocated in int array

Tags: c#, java, arrays, oop

How much space does a int array take up? Or how much space (in bytes) does a int  array consumes that looks something like this:

```
 int[] SampleArray=new int[]{1,2,3,4};
```

Is memory allocation  language specific ??

Thank you all

Comment: You forget `C`and `phtyon` tags.

Comment: This is very much language specific. Choose a language first.

Comment: In java, there is header part which cnould be fixed-size and a alignment addition which is variable so it must be bigger than elementNumber*4+8 for 64 bit system/os/jvm.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you add a lot of language tags, I want to write for C#. In C#, this depends on operating system.

For 32-bit, each `int` is 4 byte and 4 byte also for reference to the object, that makes 4 * 4 + 4 = 20 byte

For 64-bit, each `int` is 4 byte and 8 byte also for reference to the object, that makes 4 * 4 + 8 = 24 byte

From [C# 5.0 in a Nutshell](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1449320104) in page 22;

> Each reference to an object requires an extra four or eight bytes,
>   depending on whether the .NET runtime is running on a 32- or 64-bit
>   platform.

Comment: so that makes it 80 Byte as I am using 32 bit operating system...also could you explain byte for reference that is where I am stucked

Comment: Also 12 bytes overhead for the array object itself (for 32 bit code)

Comment: @MatthewWatson What is that 12 bytes for?

Answer (score 2):

In C++, how much memory `new int[4]{1, 2, 3, 4}` actually allocates is implementation-defined but the size of the array will be `sizeof(int)*4`.

Comment: This question had the c++ tag when I wrote this answer.

Comment: The syntax is not C++, so I removed the tag.

Answer (score 1):

Ques is : Is memory allocation language specific ??
Yes memory allocation is language specific..it vary according the language..
for exp:
sizeof(int)*4

in java int size is 4byte so memory consumption is: 4*4=16bytes

Answer (score 1):

It depends on both the language, but moreover to the operating system.

You need 4 integers. Normally an integer is 2 or 4 bytes (mostly 4 on most systems), but to be sure check sizeof(int).

(Also keep in mind the values can be differently represented depending on the operating system), like MSB first or LSB first (or a mix in case 4 bytes are used).

Answer (score 1):

In Java int[] array is an Object which in memory represented by the header (8 bytes for x86) and int length field (4 bytes) followed by array of ints (arrayLength * 4).

```
   approxSize = 8 + 4 + 4 * arraylength
```

see more here http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/memory/object_memory_usage.shtml